# How to stop diagonal movement - Unity 2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This my script for player movement in Unity (2d).

When two direction keys are pressed - instead of moving diagonally - I need the player to move in the most recently pressed direction (and if that is released, the direction of the already held down)

```
if (!attacking)
{
    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < -0.5f)
    {
        //transform.Translate (new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f ));
        myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * currentMoveSpeed, myRigidBody.velocity.y);
        PlayerMoving = true;
        lastMove = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f);
    }

    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < -0.5f)
    {
        //transform.Translate(new Vector3(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f));
        myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(myRigidBody.velocity.x, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * currentMoveSpeed);
        PlayerMoving = true;
        lastMove = new Vector2(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a couple of private variables, remember the previous value and compare? Are you looking for basic ideas on how to handle this or are you having trouble coding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would handle it: When only one axis is active (horizontal or vertical) remember that direction. When both are, prioritize the one that wasn't. The following code works exactly as you described but will have to be adapted to your other requirements.

```
void Update()
{
    float currentMoveSpeed = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    bool isMovingHorizontal = Mathf.Abs(horizontal) > 0.5f;

    float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    bool isMovingVertical = Mathf.Abs(vertical) > 0.5f;

    PlayerMoving = true;

    if (isMovingVertical && isMovingHorizontal)
    {
        //moving in both directions, prioritize later
        if (wasMovingVertical)
        {
            myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * currentMoveSpeed, 0);
            lastMove = new Vector2(horizontal, 0f);
        }
        else
        {
            myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, vertical * currentMoveSpeed);
            lastMove = new Vector2(0f, vertical);
        }
    }
    else if (isMovingHorizontal)
    {
        myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * currentMoveSpeed, 0);
        wasMovingVertical = false;
        lastMove = new Vector2(horizontal, 0f);
    }
    else if (isMovingVertical)
    {
        myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, vertical * currentMoveSpeed);
        wasMovingVertical = true;
        lastMove = new Vector2(0f, vertical);
    }
    else
    {
        PlayerMoving = false;
        myRigidBody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
}
```

Example result (pink line is `lastMove`):
[image: Result]