# unity 2d player movement: disable diagonal & prioritize direction of last key pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this code achieves 2d movement and disables diagonal; the 'if' statement overrides vertical movement when there is horizontal input but I cannot override horizontal movement when vertical input is detected at the same time..I would like to prioritize the direction of the last key pressed (when multiple are pressed at the same time)

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour

public float moveSpeed = 5f;

public Rigidbody2D rb;

Vector2 movement;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    // Input
    movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    //Disable diagonal movement and prioritize direction of last key pressed
    if (movement.x != 0) movement.y = 0;
    else if (movement.y != 0) movement.x = 0;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Movement
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

Comment: You can use if(vertical); else if(horizontal. This is just psuedo code but point is if one key is pressed other one won't be detected.

Comment: That's letting me achieve what I want for overriding vertical when horizontal is detected but not for overriding horizontal when vertical is detected. Basically the 'if' statement only takes care of the first direction I want to override.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! All credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3214843/manfred-radlwimmer answering basically the same question here: [How to stop diagonal movement - Unity 2d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46521943/how-to-stop-diagonal-movement-unity-2d)

Here's the specific code needed in this case:

```
// Disable diagonal movement & prioritize direction of last key pressed
    bool isMovingHorizontal = Mathf.Abs(movement.x) > 0.5f;
    bool isMovingVertical = Mathf.Abs(movement.y) > 0.5f;

    if (isMovingVertical && isMovingHorizontal)
    {
        if (wasMovingVertical)
        {
            movement.y = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            movement.x = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (isMovingHorizontal)
    {
        movement.y = 0;
        wasMovingVertical = false;
    }
    else if (isMovingVertical)
    {
        movement.x = 0;
        wasMovingVertical = true;
    }
    else
    {
        movement.x = 0;
        movement.y = 0;
    }
```